# retrieving host name from a url using php not working

Tags: php

I am trying to parse bulk urls. I have written the following code to do that. it's not parsing urls correctly. I do need your suggestions what I may need to change/alter in order the code to work. Thank you.

```
$expr = '[^https*://([^:/]+):?(\d*)/([^?]*)\??(.*)]';
$matches = array();
$fh = fopen('urls.txt', 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
while (!feof($fh)) {
    $item = fgets($fh);
    if (preg_match($expr, $item, $matches)) {
       list($host, $port, $dir, $args) = array_splice($matches, 1, 4);
       print "Host=>$host\n";
       print "Port=>$port\n";
       print "Dir=>$dir\n";
       print "Arguments=>$args\n";
    } else {
        print "Doesn't match.\n";
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: What is it doing "incorrectly"?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the parse_url() function instead of your regex?

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_url

```
$matches = array();
$fh = fopen('urls.txt', 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
while (!feof($fh)) {
    $item = fgets($fh);
    $tmp = parse_url($item);
    if( isset($tmp['host']) ) {
      print "Host=".$tmp['host']."\n";
      print "Port=".$tmp['port']."\n";
      print "Dir=".$tmp['path']."\n";
      print "Host=".$tmp['query']."\n";
    } else {
       print "Doesn't match.\n";
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```